# K8s http Liveness probe failed just on 1 worker node

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core

I have .netcore 2.2 API Pod on my K8S Farm i implement health check api to let k8s liveness check.
Here is My settings.

```
     livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /api/Authentication/CheckLiveness
          port: 80
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 100
        timeoutSeconds: 60
        periodSeconds: 30
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 1
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /api/Authentication/CheckReadiness
          port: 80
          scheme: HTTP
        initialDelaySeconds: 50
        timeoutSeconds: 30
        periodSeconds: 15
        successThreshold: 1
        failureThreshold: 1
```

The Problem is other worker node seem working find without problem except pod on worker node 1.

[image: Error Pod on WorkerNode1]

Here is the error event.

```
Liveness probe failed: Get 
http://10.244.3.218:80/api/Authentication/CheckLiveness:net/http: 
request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Readiness probe failed: Get 
http://10.244.3.218:80/api/Authentication/CheckReadiness: net/http: 
request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I can curl to my pod by exec it. But the pod keep restarting.

I think it a node Problem. This K8s Farm run on Vmware with centos7 os.
I tried this config on dev environment with the same infrastructure. and it all green without problem. 
Need any suggestion to debug or solve this problem.
Thank you.

@mWatney Edited

And here your result

```
Name:           authenservice-dpm-7d468bfcc4-px44m
Namespace:      pbtsapi
Priority:       0
Node:           ptseclsbtwkn01/192.168.10.136
Start Time:     Fri, 12 Jun 2020 11:23:07 +0700
Labels:         app=authenservice-api
                pod-template-hash=7d468bfcc4
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.3.218
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/authenservice-dpm-7d468bfcc4
Containers:
  authenservice:
    Container ID:   docker://1b1acffeae54421201d1bbc54b8020a75db660e1ae1a0f0d18a56930bbca0d12
    Image:          10.99.21.89:5000/authenservice:v1.0.4
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://10.99.21.89:5000/authenservice@sha256:b9244059195edff3cc3592d3e19a94ac00e481e9936413a4315a3cf41b0023ea
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 12 Jun 2020 14:46:22 +0700
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 12 Jun 2020 14:37:52 +0700
      Finished:     Fri, 12 Jun 2020 14:46:21 +0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  28
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  400Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      250m
      memory:   200Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:80/api/Authentication/CheckLiveness delay=300s timeout=60s period=30s #success=1 #failure=1
    Readiness:  http-get http://:80/api/Authentication/CheckReadiness delay=300s timeout=60s period=30s #success=1 #failure=1
    Environment:
      MSSQL_PORT:  1433
    Mounts:
      /app/appsettings.json from authen-v (rw,path="appsettings.json")
      /etc/localtime from tz-config (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-h8x2b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  authen-v:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      authenservice-config
    Optional:  false
  tz-config:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Bangkok
    HostPathType:  
  default-token-h8x2b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-h8x2b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                     -------
  Normal   Killing    22m (x26 over 3h23m)    kubelet, ptseclsbtwkn01  Container authenservice failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  Unhealthy  6m42s (x28 over 3h23m)  kubelet, ptseclsbtwkn01  Liveness probe failed: Get http://10.244.3.218:80/api/Authentication/CheckLiveness: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  10s (x22 over 3h8m)     kubelet, ptseclsbtwkn01  Readiness probe failed: Get http://10.244.3.218:80/api/Authentication/CheckReadiness: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: Identical settings for liveness and readiness probe is always a mistake: https://srcco.de/posts/kubernetes-liveness-probes-are-dangerous.html

Comment: @zerkms Thank you will take a look in your link. btw if it break should it failed with every node?

Comment: Please, avoid posting images of code and logs. [Check here why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Can you update your question, remove these images and put your code in text mode and share the output for `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl describe pod **podname**`?

Comment: @mWatney Thank you for your kindness. Edited as your suggested.

Comment: may be it takes more then 35 seconds for your app to be ready. Rise the timeout to like 300 seconds, and try then.

Comment: @suren i will try

Comment: @suren try on your config it still the same error.

Comment: Did my answer helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual Machines are never identical. You can setup Virtual Machines with identical specs, by doing this you make sure they will have similarities but it doesn't mean they will perform exactly the same.

Same thing happens to servers. You can buy two identical physical servers and they will perform similarly but never identically.

Logs are clearly saying that by the time that the application was tested, it wasn't ready yet.

As [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) said, you can't have identical rediness and liveness probes. You definitely have  to review this. You have also to review your readiness probe `initialDelaySeconds`. Try increasing it to give more time for your application to start.

To troubleshoot, [suren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5564578/suren) suggestion and increase your timeout, I would increase the `initialDelaySeconds` instead.

Comment: I done it as Readiness initialDelaySeconds  90 and Liveness initialDelaySeconds   60 and it still the same.

Comment: @PeeradisSa-nguanTrakul I really recommend you read that article again: liveness probe under no circumstances should have timeouts/delays lower than readiness.

Comment: @zerkms yes I read it and I set Liveness both timeouts/delays lower then Readiness.

Comment: The same for initial delay: a service can not become non-liveness before becoming ready

Comment: @zerkms yes I understand that liveness should pass before readiness check correctly so the initial delay should be lower To make sure the liveness check pass properly.

Comment: @PeeradisSa-nguanTrakul it's the opposite: readiness should happen first: something cannot "die" before getting "ready". `new -> ready -> unresponsive -> killed` <- this is the cycle

Comment: @zerkms Ok. Sorry for my poor English reading. I try it again with your suggestion and it still the same. I will edit the last config in the post.

Comment: If you remove tour livenessProbe completely what happens?

Comment: @PeeradisSa-nguanTrakul my suggestion was not supposed to _fix_ the problem, but to help make your configuration more logical. Regarding your problem: if an endpoint does not respond successfully - it's nothing to do with probes, but with the application. Check the app logs, contact the app developers to find out how to discover what's wrong with the app itself.

Comment: @zerkms Thank you. I will consult with Dev and Infra.

Comment: So if you leave only your readinessProbe and remove the livenessProbe it works fine? If yes, it proves what @zerkms is saying. Your Probes are conflicting.

Comment: @mWatney Nope it still Readiness Probe Failed.

Comment: @PeeradisSa-nguanTrakul and with only the Readiness Probe it still work on one node and fails in the other?

Comment: @mWatney failed on one node but work on every node.

Comment: If you test the probe manually on this node it's working? Do you have other applications running on this node? I think this node might have a networking problem.

Comment: @mWatney We have rabbitmq and redis but both work fine on every node.

Comment: If you test the probe manually on this node it's working?

Comment: @mWatney you mean create only 1 Pod to test probe on the workernode 1 only?

Comment: No, I mean checking it the probe is giving the right answer from inside the pod using `kubectl exec -ti podname -- sh`.

Comment: Have you tested it on all nodes?

Comment: Increasing timeout is not working. Any idea how to fix the liveness probe failed issue ?

Answer (score 1):

So i consult with app team and infra team.
App team confirm that app working correctly so infra team try remove the problem node and then add new node to the cluster.
The problem is solved But sadly that i can't find the root cause of the problem. But i guess it node problem after all.
Thank you @mWatney and @zerkms for your help and suggestion + best practices.